# Creating Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby and I wanted to test how to create gem file. I have followings installed in my machine. 
ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]
Bundler version 1.2.3
rake, version 10.0.3

I created a gem using `bundle gem hello_gem`. I added following sample code to  `hello_gem.rb`

```
module HelloGem
  class Base
    def self.hello
      puts "Hello Ruby Gem #{HelloGem::VERSION}"
    end
  end
end
```

My folder structure is like follows.

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── hello_gem.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── hello_gem
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── hello_gem.rb
├── LICENSE.txt
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
```

Then I created the gem using `rake install`. Then I started `irb` and I can execute following.

```
1.9.3-p362 :001 > require 'hello_gem'
 => true 
1.9.3-p362 :002 > HelloGem::Base.hello
Hello Ruby Gem 0.0.1
 => nil 
1.9.3-p362 :003 >
```

Problem comes when I wanted to move code to lib folder. I created `lib/hello_gem/base.rb` and added the above code there. And in the `hello_gem.rb` I just used `require "hello_gem/base"`. Now my project look like follows.

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── hello_gem.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── hello_gem
│   │   ├── base.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── hello_gem.rb
├── LICENSE.txt
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
```

When I build the gem using `rake install` and use `irb` to test following error happened.

```
1.9.3-p362 :001 > require 'hello_gem'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- hello_gem/base
from /home/sandarenu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/sandarenu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/sandarenu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/hello_gem-0.0.1/lib/hello_gem.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/sandarenu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /home/sandarenu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /home/sandarenu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from (irb):1
from /home/sandarenu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p362 :002 >
```

I can't find a way to fix this issue. It would be a great help if somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://pastie.org/5805403. Are you sure you open a fresh IRB for the test?

Comment: might help https://shivab.com/blog/ruby/2019/08/30/convert-your-ruby-script-to-a-ruby-gem/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.gemspec` created by `bundle gem` uses [Git](http://git-scm.com/) to determine which files to include in the gem; it contains the line:

```
gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
```

In order for it to add your `hello_gem/base.rb` you need to add it to the Git repository. Since the original setup works for you I assume you have Git installed, so you just need to run:

```
git add lib/hello_gem/base.rb
```

You don’t actually need to commit the file for `git ls-files` to pick it up and add it to the gem, so this should be enough to get it to work.

Comment: Ah, I remember now. Had this problem with my own gem some time ago. :)

Comment: OMG!... It really worked :). I just published the sample code to [github](https://github.com/sandarenu/hello_gem), before checking your answer. Now it is working. I was struggling with this issue for many hours. None of the tutorials I checked didn't had this issue specified. Thank you very much.